# Drupal: Access $profile from a block

Tags: drupal, drupal-blocks

I'm trying to get the avatar (profile picture) located in the $profile array to appear in a BLOCK. The variable $profile is not accessible from blocks. It's scope is only in that actual user-profile.tpl.php file. So... does anybody know how I can execute something like this:

```
print $profile[user_picture];
```

in a drupal BLOCK?

Comment: So far I can only imagine it has something to do with these:
http://api.lullabot.com/file/core/modules/profile/profile-block.tpl.php
and these:
http://api.drupal.org/api/function/template_preprocess_profile_block/7

Comment: You mention below that you found the answer by creating a view block - any chance of sharing the technique?

Comment: Yay. First time I get to help someone! :-) Basically, I wanted that if you click on user X's profile, that it shows his name in a block. To do this, I created a view that displays a user's name. I then let this view take in a the uid as an argument and voila. 

I eventually extended it a bit using a module called "insert view" so that I can do some funky PHP commands. Let me know if I must give more instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured i might as well post it here as well. See my second comment on the first thread in this discussion. Below is my code I used with INSERT VIEW to get what I wanted:

```
<?php 
       $profileUser = "";
       if (arg(0) == "user") {
            $profileUser = arg(1);
       }
       // removed some other checks i do to populate $profileUser
?>

[view:VIEWED_PROFILE_AVATAR=block=<?php print $profileUser; ?>]
```

I hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the following code in a new block (`admin/build/block/add`):

```
<?php
global $user;
$output = theme_image($user->picture, $alt = 'user pic', $title = 'user pic');
print $output;
```

This gives you access to the global `$user` variable and then you can use the picture property to get the URL for the current users profile picture.

Comment: Yes, but that's not the picture I want. If I'm viewing somebody else's profile, i want to be able to see that person's picture. I solved it by creating a block view.